# pylint shows import-error with directories inside the working directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, discord.py, pylint

After installing a new version of Python(from 3.8.1 to 3.8.3) and using it with Visual Studio Code, I've encountered an issue with pylint that did not happen prior the upgrade.

My working directory tree is as follows:

```
bot
 ┣ cogs
 ┃ ┗ cog.py
 ┣ utils
 ┃ ┗ __init__.py
 ┃ ┗ format.py
 ┣ __init__.py
 ┣ core.py
run.py
```

`run.py` is the script's "entry point" that initializes everything, doing `import bot` inside it works just fine and pylint has no problems with it. Relative imports have no problems with pylint either as `core.py` uses `from .utils import ...`.

However, when doing `from bot.utils import ...` inside `cog.py`, pylint keeps showing an `import-error` problem which shouldn't show up because the code runs just fine.

I am confused why this problem was not present before the upgrade, did I do anything wrong and if so, how can I change this behavior?

Comment: Before anyone suggests doing relative imports inside `cog.py`, I am aware it's possible but it would personally affect readability for me.

Comment: do a relative import inside cog.py.  It's the python way.  You will get tripped up if you don't.  Despite readability, you need to do it as habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need to change anything in regards of VSC or pylint, I added a `__init__.py` file inside cogs and it worked, for some weird reason.